# A prototyping language with the ability to be fast

Tags: math, prototype, lisp, artificial-intelligence, go

as an engineering student with a strong mathemathical background, i dealing some problems like this at university:

- (numerical) Simulations
- AI Problems
- Robotics
- Control Systems
- and some more

as you can see some are just numerical ones, others have to process some kinds of symbols.
currently i'm working with java, but i'm not very pleased with it (can't say exactly why, probably a personal taste) and now i'm searching for a programming language, in which i can easily prototype new algorithms, like for example in python, and don't care about low level stuff, but has the ability to speed things up if neccessary, e.g. with concurrent/parallel programming, etc. (writing it in python and rewrite it in C/C++ isn't really a option i prefer...)

to sum it up:

- easy to prototype, but
- the ability to speed algorithms up
- syntax without boilerplate stuff like in java
- syntax which is easy to read (i know this could be achived with the most, but some language encourage you more...)

i've looked around at sites, like http://rosettacode.org/ and picked 2 or 3 favorites: Go, Lisp (and maybe Haskell) but other recommandations are welcome

Comment: sorry, forgot that, it should be for free (although i could get matlab for free at university)

Comment: I wish someone would write python in Lisp, so we'd have the ease of programming without the overhead during execution ;-) That with numpy would probably be your ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp using SBCL is pretty fast if you take the time to make it fast.

Why does this fit what you want?

- symbolic computations
- good number handling
- compiles to native <s>on demand</s> by default.

Comment: it compiles to native code by default

Answer (score 4):

I would use python together with cython: http://www.cython.org for speeding up your code. For symbolic computations you have http://code.google.com/p/sympy/

Comment: despite the downvote: if I read your "sum it up", python is the ideal language for your task.... writing extensions in cython is just writing the python code with some type declarations added... and it uses the distutils build process, no extra framework, no extra build tool....

Comment: nice recommendation, never considered cython, i definitly will give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try Clojure; it fulfills most of your requirements.

- Uses Java libraries, compiles to Java bytecode, and has plugins for Java IDEs, so some of your existing knowledge about Java and its ecosystem will come in handy.
- Very concise, readable, and ease of prototyping is extremely high.
- Great support for different concurrency strategies.
- Performance is getting better fast; typical stuff is within a speed factor of 2 of Java, and slow things can typically be made fast with minimally confounding changes (e.g. a few type hints here and there to use Java primitives.)

Comment: This is a really great language, but I found it even harder to learn the common lisp

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Common Lisp would be a implementation of scheme. My favorite so far is Racket.

http://racket-lang.org/

When I first got into Lisp I started with scheme and ended up being able to learn it within a matter of days. Also Lisp-wise Racket is a pretty complete language and has a decent IDE in DrRacket.

Answer (score 2):

How about F#?

F# is a remarkable language for prototyping for the following reasons:

F# has an interactive mode allowing you to evaluate blocks of code directly, without compiling your entire project.
Type inference helps keep code small, and makes refactoring your type hierarchy relatively painless. This may not be so important in production code, but I found that to be very valuable during prototyping.
F# integration with .NET makes it easy to prototype extensions of your existing products. In the all-too-common case when a prototype becomes a product (due to time constraints), it's also easy to integrate your F# code within your .NET product.
If prototyping makes up a significant part of your overall development process, then F# can really help you speed up your coding.

I don't think F# will produce code that is significantly faster than other .NET languages. The functional style of programming, in particular purity (no side-effects), can be applied to other programming languages, meaning it is just as easy to write concurrent programs in other languages as well. It does however "feel more natural" to do so in F#.

F# has the Option type, which can be used in place of null values. Code reliability with respect to null-pointer exceptions can be guaranteed at compile time, which is a huge benefit.

Finally, be advised that F# is still in development, and suffers issues, some of which may disappear over time, but not all. See for instance what devhawk and Oliver Sturm have to say about it (in particular about linear scoping and interdependent classes, other issues like overloading, better Visual Studio integration have already been addressed).

this is stated in article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328329/why-should-i-use-f

by JOH

Comment: do you know how mature the mono project is already? i'm using linux as my main os

Comment: I'd say mono is reaching a good level of maturity, I've never had a problem from it